# PHP pcntl module installation

Tags: php

> Problems

1. d11wtq/boris v1.0.10 requires ext-pcntl * -> the requested PHP extension pcntl is missing from your system.
2. d11wtq/boris v1.0.10 requires ext-pcntl * -> the requested PHP extension pcntl is missing from your system.
3. Installation request for d11wtq/boris v1.0.10 -> satisfiable by d11wtq/boris[v1.0.10].

When I run command: composer install it creating error.

And also how to install extension on php.init.

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Comment: please specify the OS as well. have you tried with Wamp or Linux?

Answer (score 30):

I know this is an old one, but I ran into the same problem and with this switch just solved it:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Answer (score 26):

I fixed this by running `composer update` before install.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me with Drush installation.

Comment: thanks. this helped me to install laravel-admin.org admin panel

Answer (score 10):

Solved my problem updating and ignoring requested PHP extensions:

`composer update --ignore-platform-reqs`

Answer (score 9):

http://php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php

> Process Control support in PHP is not enabled by default. You have to
>   compile the CGI or CLI version of PHP with --enable-pcntl
>   configuration option when compiling PHP to enable Process Control
>   support.
>
> Note:
>   Currently, this module will not function on non-Unix platforms (Windows).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my system (OpenSUSE, PHP7). Simply installing php7-pcntl solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can resolve this issue by following way.

Your options are as follows:

- Install the required extensions (best option)
- Run composer with the --ignore-platform-reqs flag (very hacky) like `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs`
- Upgrade to Laravel 5 (we no longer user boris for the tinker command)