# Laravel package class not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I have installed laravel packages on staging server and packages working fine. But when i take pull on staging server, it is showing me error that package class not found.

Steps I have followed to resolve issue

1. I have check in vendor folder as well as in config/app.php, but I got class declaration and package folder is there.
2. After this when I update composer, my issue get resolved.

Is there any other file which should i look for class defination?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... never run `update composer` on server it should be in local and test newer verion work then only move to live then in server run `composer install --prefer-dist --no-scripts --no-progress --no-suggest --no-interaction --no-dev`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42065931/why-should-i-never-run-composer-update-in-production for more info

Answer (score 0):

Perform a **composer update**, then **composer dump-autoload**.

If the above doesn't solve the problem, change the **classmap** in your **composer.json** file such that it contains the project-relative path to your php files:

```
"autoload-dev": {
"classmap": [
    "tests/TestCase.php",
    "database/seeds/UserTableSeeder.php" //include the file with its path here
]},
```

and soon after, perform a composer dump-autoload, and it should work now